# When multiple conditions are using index condition, combine them(using or operator) together, would it still be performant?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoid

We have a system, which are using rails and mongoid, in the system post can have comments,
and comments can have any nested level,
so I use nested set to implement it,
then post's top level comments need to be paginated,
let's say

```
comments=post.comments.page(1).per(10)
```

then I want all those's descendants:

```
or_conditions = comments.map { |comment| { post_id: comment.post.id, :lft.gte => comment.lft, :lft.lte => comment.rgt}}
all_comments=Comment.or(*or_conditions)
```

I'm using mongo, each part it will use IXSCAN,but oring them together,will it still be performant? (it means Comment.or(cond1).or(cond2).or(cond3), and each part is using IXSCAN).
Also I would like to extend this to sql database, if each part of condition is using index, does or them together still be performant?

Comment: i think yes, it will. but consider to use `limit` for each query. since its a comment app, consider to `re-fetch` when its trying to get sub comment as well. it would be like Youtube comment, instagram, tiktok etc.